# PHP Loop Start at Record Number

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have 2 tables. One floated to the left, one floated to the right. Each table contains 8 rows of which I want to display the results of my query. I want the table on the left to display the first 8 records and the table on the right to display the following 8. Right now I'm stuck trying to figure out how to get the table on the right to display record numbers 8 - 16.

Here's my loop on the table on the left:

```
<?php do { ?>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><?php echo $row_rsSystems['systemName']; ?></td>
      </tr>
      <?php } while ($row_rsSystems = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsSystems)); ?>
```

Comment: What if you pushed all of the rows into a PHP array first, then executed the code to generate the table after you have all the data in an index-accessible format?

Comment: Since u are using 2 tables.you can use 2 queries and make use of limit and offset to filter database results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, not sure how your tables look but you can just do two queries and add a `LIMIT` to both.

First one: `LIMIT 0, 8`

Second one: `LIMIT 8, 8`

Might not be the best way to do it but it works.

Comment: Shouldn't the first one be `0, 4` and the second `4, 4`?

Comment: No. He wants `0-8` then `8-16`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    <table>

        <?php

        $i = 0;
        while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array($result) ){
            if ($i % 2 == 0){
                echo '<tr>';
            }
            echo '<td>'.$row['systemName'].'</td>';
            if ($i % 2 == 8){
                echo '</tr>';
            }
            $i++; 
        }

        //here is a check in case you don't have multiple of 3 rows
        if ($i % 8 != 0){
            echo '</tr>';
        }

        ?>

        </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do/While method of handling mysql results is probably not necessary; use the following instead:

```
$results = mysql_query($query, $connection);
while ($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)) { 
    echo $result['systemName'];
}
```

As far as skipping ahead to a certain record you can do this with an iterator:

```
$results = mysql_query($query, $connection);

$i = 0;
$skipahead = 8; //skip to the 8th record:


while ($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)) { 
    if($i<$skipahead) continue; //this performs the skip
    echo $result['systemName'];
    $i++; //increment
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should work:

```
<?php $i = 0; ?>
```

and for each table:

```
 <?php while ($row_rsSystems = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsSystems) && (++$i % 8)) {?>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><?php echo $row_rsSystems['systemName']; ?></td>
      </tr>
 <?php } ?>
```

Make a function of the above to avoid c&p.

Your query should only fetch 16 entries if you need to display only 16 (use the `LIMIT` keyword), and if you need to display the next batches (say, 16-32) include that parameter as well in your query (keyword `OFFSET`).

[mysql SELECT documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) for mentioned keywords.

Answer (score 0):

First you might wanna use `while(){}` rather than `do{...}while();`.
For separating the data into two tables I suggest you use two temporary arrays for storing the data and then use them to create your desired tables.
Something like this:

```
$i = 0;
while($row_rsSystems = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsSystems)){
    if($i < 8){
       //stuff for the left table
       $right_table = array(...);
    }else{
       //stuff for the right table
       $left_table = array(...);
    }
    $i++;
}
```

This way you have all the data in one go for the sake of optimality.

Comment: I would like to know how we can start and end the two tables inside this while loop

Comment: :) I must apologize for my hasty answer. What I meant is to first use two distinctive arrays for storing data temporarily and then use these arrays respectively to create the table.